# How to read s3 data from one EMR cluster to another EMR cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am having two EMR clusters and One EMR Cluster having CSV files in S3 bucket.
Now, I am having another EMR cluster and have to read the data from the EMR(s3) bucket.

Please find the screenshot.

[image]

How to read the data from another EMR s3 bucket? Input source is S3 bucket to read the csv files. In same EMR i can read the data from s3 bucket.

Kindly help me.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 is an independent amazon web service, S3 is not tied to any EMR particular cluster, you can access a single S3 bucket from any number of consumers (EMR in this case) the same way, just make sure the AWS IAM policies/permissions are correct.